# Find the area of polygon whose sides are known [C++]

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, area

I'm trying to the find the area of a shape for which I've only been given the length of the sides. 
Considering the shape to be a quadrilateral (having only four sides) for now, what is the method(or algo) to find its area in C++? (Given that the lengths of the sides of a quadrilateral are fixed, the resultant area of any quad shape obtained will be always equal.)

Note that I do not have the vertices of the shape and have only the sides. If at all, I'd have had the vertices, I could have used the [this summation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Area_and_centroid) to directly get the area of a n-sided polygon. But what's the best way to deal with this constraint?

Comment: There is no single solution (you need some angles between two edges) Assume four edges having the length of one: The number of parallelograms matching is infinite.

Comment: If you only have side lengths then you cannot calculate the area. If you have four equal sides it could be a square or a an infinite number of rhombus.

Answer (score 5):

You can't. You don't have enough information to make the calculation without knowing at least 2 of angles in addition to your lengths or more detail about the type of object that is more specific then a quadrilateral.

Reason: A quadrilateral has 4 sides. No other limits. In fact, the lines can intersect creating even more difficulty in calculation of the area.

Comment: at least three angles == all four angles. I'm not convinced you need 3; I believe two consecutive right angles is strong enough.

Comment: Good point. You could use 2 angles and the lengths of the other 2 legs to derive the other 2 angles.

Comment: @DieterLücking. I think you would need 2 angles. If this was a closed form then you would be correct, but what if 2 of the lines intersected?  think of a bow-tie. http://www.mathsisfun.com/quadrilaterals.html

Comment: Two consecutive sides and their inner angle is enough since it gives you an SAS triangle and an SSS triangle.